# AmCharts v3 selectively hide graph legend item (not toggle graph)

Tags: amcharts

I'm supporting a legacy amCharts installation and I need to be able to selectively toggle the legend items visibility. I don't mean toggle the graph using the legend. I mean remove the legend item from the legend

The user has a checkbox list where they can select the graphs they want to appear. Until now, ALL graphs have been rendered but just toggled accordingly based on the user's selection.

Now, I want to actually hide the legend items for graphs that were not selected by the user. As opposed to having all legend items there, but with some ON and some OFF.

So here, I would want to remove all of the greyed-out items and leave the rest
[image]

While the debugger is paused just before the `validateData` method, I can make the legend item hide by executing this `$scope.barChart.graphs[14].legendEntry.hide()` but it reappears after `validateData` has executed. Is there a way to prevent this from reappearing?

In the console you can see the `$scope.barChart.graphs[14].legendEntry.hide()`
[image: z]

In this screenshot there is a loading mask present, hence the low contrast, but you can see that the `FB Total Views` item is not there. This is what I'm after, but ideally they would re-render without gaps

[image]
Here's my chart config below.

```
this.barChartOptions = {
    listeners: [{
        event: "rendered",
        method: function (e) {

        }
    }, {
        event: "drawn",
        method: function (e) {
            e.chart.zoomToIndexes(0, 19);
        }
    }],
    data: [],
    type: "serial",
    zoomOutText: '',
    titles: [{ text: "" }],
    rotate: false,
    zoomOutOnDataUpdate: true,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: '"Montserrat", sans-serif',
    creditsPosition: "bottom-right",
    autoTransform: false,
    chartScrollbar: {
        enabled: true,
        backgroundColor: scrollbarGBColor,
        selectedBackgroundColor: scrollbarColor,
        dragCursorHover: "cursor: move;",
        dragCursorDown: "cursor: grab;"
    },
    autoMargins: true,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 80,
    marginBottom: 50,
    marginTop: 20,

    pathToImages: '',
    angle: 30,
    depth3D: 0,
    export: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        listeners: [{
            "event": "clickMarker",
            "method": function(event) {
              // toggle the marker state
              event.dataItem.hidden = !event.dataItem.hidden; 
              event.chart.validateNow();
            }
          }],
        enabled: true,
        useGraphSettings: true,
        divId: "barChartLegenddiv",
        position: "relative",
        bottom: 0,
        valueText: "[[value]]",
        "beforeCapture": function () {

        },
    },
    //listeners: [{ "event": "init", "method": $scope.addListeners(this) }],
    categoryField: "ClientName",
    categoryAxis: {
        autoWrap: true,
        maxSeries: 0,
        gridPosition: "start",
        parseDates: false,
        labelRotation: 0,
        boldLabels: false

        //labelFunction: function (valueText, serialDataItem, categoryAxis) {
        //    if (valueText.length > 20)
        //        return valueText.substring(0, 20) + '...';
        //    else
        //        return valueText;
        //}
    },
    valueAxes: [{
        strictMinMax: true,
        minimum: 0,
        stackType: "none",
        position: "top",
        title: "",
        includeAllValues: true
    }],
        graphs: this.analyticsBarChartGraphs
    };


this.analyticsBarChartGraphs = [
    {
        "valueField": "CustomerViewCount",
        "balloonText": "Customer Photo Views: <b>[[CustomerViewCount]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#a4e4b5",
        "lineColor": "#69bd80",
        "title": "Customer Photo Views",
        "labelOffset": 20,
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "OwnerViewCount",
        "balloonText": "Owner Photo Views: <b>[[OwnerViewCount]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#009eff",
        "lineColor": "#004d7c",
        "title": "Owner Photo Views",
        "labelOffset": 20
        , "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "TotalSearches",
        "balloonText": "Total Searches: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#4e8602",
        "lineColor": "#165042",
        "title": "Total Searches",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "labelOffset": 20
    }, {
        "valueField": "DirectSearches",
        "balloonText": "Direct Searches: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#4c9900",
        "lineColor": "#004d22",
        "title": "Direct Searches",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "labelOffset": 20
    }, {
        "valueField": "DirectionsActions",
        "balloonText": "Directions Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#ff7900",
        "lineColor": "#802f00",
        "title": "Directions Actions",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "labelOffset": 20
    }, {
        "valueField": "PhoneCallActions",
        "balloonText": "Phone Call Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#ffc490",
        "lineColor": "#8a670f",
        "title": "Phone Call Actions",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "labelOffset": 20
    }, {
        "valueField": "GmbTotalPhotoViews",
        "balloonText": "GMB Total Photo Views: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#fc0000",
        "lineColor": "#a00000",
        "title": "GMB Total Photo Views",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "labelOffset": 20
    }, {    // FB items vv
        "valueField": "FBTotalViews",
        "balloonText": "FB Total Views: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#1E4A68",
        "lineColor": "#0b1c28",
        "title": "FB Total Views",
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "FBDiscoverySearches",
        "balloonText": "FB Discovery Searches: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#8DC63F",
        "lineColor": "#45621d",
        "title": "FB Discovery Searches",
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "FBTotalActions",
        "balloonText": "FB Total Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#F6892B",
        "lineColor": "#ab5407",
        "title": "FB Total Actions",
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "FBWebsiteActions",
        "balloonText": "FB Website Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#FFF200",
        "lineColor": "#807900",
        "title": "FB Website Actions",
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "FBDirectionsActions",
        "balloonText": "FB Directions Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#FF5E04",
        "lineColor": "#802f00",
        "title": "FB Directions Actions",
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "FBPhoneCallActions",
        "balloonText": "FB Phone Call Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#eab73a",
        "lineColor": "#8a670f",
        "title": "FB Phone Call Actions",
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, {
        "valueField": "FBLikesTotal",
        "balloonText": "FB Page Likes: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#0000fc",
        "lineColor": "#0000a0",
        "title": "FB Page Likes",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
    }, {
        "valueField": "FBPagePlacesCheckInTotal",
        "balloonText": "FB Phone Call Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": "#3f5c98",
        "lineColor": "#0000a0",
        "title": "FB Page Places Check In Total",
        "labelText": "[[value]]"
    }, ...
...
...
...{
        "valueField": "yelpPhoneCallActions",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "balloonText": "Yelp Phone Call Actions: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "type": "column",
        "fillColors": "#eab73a",
        "lineColor": "#8a670f",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "title": "Yelp Phone Call Actions"
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it's actually quite simple to [hide a legend item](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#visibleInLegend):

`$scope.barChart.graphs[g].visibleInLegend = false`

I looped over the `graph` collection and set them all to false, then selectively made them visible where necessary